# What are key differences between UML and design patterns (GoF)?

Tags: design-patterns, uml

how are they different? What is common between them?

Comment: GoF patterns are described using UML diagrams. Your question does not make sense.

Comment: @darlinton: it only doesn't make sense when you understand the answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UML is just a notation for describing object-oriented software models, nothing more.  It's the unification of competing notations by Grady Booch, Ivar Jacobsen, and Jim Rumbaugh.  After duking it out for years, they became the "Three Amigoes" and combined their ideas into UML.  It's been maintained and extended by Object Management Group (OMG) for quite some time, since at least 1998.

"Design Patterns" was a book by "The Gang of Four", published in 1995.  It suggested that common problems in object-oriented systems had common solutions.   They gave a format for documenting patterns (forces, solutions, etc.) and offered examples in C++ and Smalltalk (there were no Java or C# at the time).  The ideas transcend language.

They put names to those common problems.  That was their biggest contribution.  Singleton and Factory are just part of the lexicon now.

A mania for patterns was kicked off.  There were lots of conferences and books devoted to them.

I think both are long past their tulip bulb bubbles.  UML and design patterns are orthogonal: Neither one had influence on the other that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

They're unrelated. UML is simply a modeling methodology and language whereas GoF patterns are basically techniques applicable to software. You can use UML to document GoF paterns but thsts about as tight the relationship between the two get.